# modifying date with php

Tags: php, mysql

Basically that is the function that I use to extract the date from the php and modify it:

```
      function getAge()
  {
         $result= mysql_query("SELECT date_of_birth 
                        FROM controlpanel 
                        WHERE user_id=".$this->userID) or die(mysql_error());
         $year="";
          if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
          {
               $row['date_of_birth'];
          }


  }
```

$row['date_of_birth']; I want to get the year from that row, and check if it is 0000..if it is I want to return  return "Not given";.. if it isnt, I want to compare the full date d-m-y to todays date.. in order to get the persons birth date..however, I am not sure what date functions to use..

Comment: What type/format is date_of_birth being stored as? For example, is it a date type or varchar?

Comment: y-m-d... like a usual database date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( substr($row['date_of_birth'],0,4) == "0000") echo "Not given";
```

Comment: that answe is incorrect, cause the date is like this 00-00-0000; may be 0 and then 2

Comment: Erm, no, the date in a databae is 0000-00-00, unless you're using a varchar instead of a proper date field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$year = date("Y", $row['date_of_birth']);

if ($year == 0000) {
    return "Not given";
}

return date("d m Y", $row['date_of_birth']);
```

Comment: Not a good answer. `$row['date_of_birth']` is a string, not a unix timestamp, and `0000` is just `0`.

Comment: I want the date to be returned ..minus todays date..so that i will ge the persons age

Comment: it gives me this: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\ControlPanel\class_user.php on line 76

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the 4 digit year from your result:
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($row['date_of_birth']);

then, you can use a function like the one on the following page to get the age:

http://www.geekpedia.com/code79_Calculate-age-from-birth-date.html

or other solutions:
http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php+get+age+from+birthday

Answer (score 0):

need to add some quotes to declare the 0000 as string cause if you use 0000 not "0000" php will just read it as 0

```
$year = date("Y", $row['date_of_birth']);
if ($year == "0000") {
    return "Invalid year";
}
else{
    return "Valid year";
}
```